# Aspose.Words shape.remove() not fully effective

Tags: java, aspose.words

I want to replace images to text but when I remove the shape nodes,As a result, some of the pictures are not deleted. 
Why?

```
    public void replaceImageToMark() throws Exception {
    Document doc = new Document("D:\\company\\demo.docx");
    NodeCollection shapeCollection = doc.getChildNodes(NodeType.DRAWING_ML, true);
    for (int i = 0; i < shapeCollection.getCount(); i++) {
        DrawingML drawingML = (DrawingML) shapeCollection.get(i);
        if (drawingML.hasImage()) {
            String imageFileName = java.text.MessageFormat.format(
                    "Image.ExportImages.{0} Out{1}", i, FileFormatUtil.imageTypeToExtension(drawingML.getImageData().getImageType()));
            DrawingMLImageData imageData = drawingML.getImageData();
            imageData.save("D:\\company\\pic\\" + imageFileName);
            DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
            builder.moveTo(drawingML);
            builder.write("${image}");
            drawingML.remove(); // There are some images that are not effective
        }
    }
    doc.save("D:\\company\\newDemo.docx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using older version of Aspose.Words. I suggest you please use latest version of [Aspose.Words for Java 18.4](https://artifact.aspose.com/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/repo/com/aspose/aspose-words/18.4). Please replace DrawingML with Shape in your code as shown below to get the desired output.

```
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + "in.docx");

NodeCollection shapeCollection = doc.getChildNodes(NodeType.SHAPE, true);
for (int i = 0; i < shapeCollection.getCount(); i++) {
    Shape shape = (Shape) shapeCollection.get(i);
    if (shape.hasImage()) {
        String imageFileName = java.text.MessageFormat.format(
                "Image.ExportImages.{0} Out{1}", i, FileFormatUtil.imageTypeToExtension(shape.getImageData().getImageType()));
        shape.getImageData().save("D:\\company\\pic\\" + imageFileName);
        DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
        builder.moveTo(shape);
        builder.write("${image}");
        shape.remove();  
    }
}
doc.save(MyDir + "output.docx");
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.